# will_paginate for search result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, will-paginate

I am using will_paginate gem for the pagination on my application. I have created a search action with the following code.

Controller

```
def index
     @transactions = Transaction.all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
end

def search
    @transactions = Transaction.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10).where(:created_at => params[:from_date].to_datetime..(params[:to_date].to_datetime + 1.day))
end
```

search.js.erb

```
$("#searchResult").replaceWith('<div id = "searchResult"><%=j render 'result' %></div>');
```

_result.thml.erb

```
<div>
<%= @transactions.each do |f| %>
......
......
<% end %>
</div>
<%= will_paginate @transactions %>
```

index.html.erb

```
<div id = "searchResult">
<%= render = "result"%>
<% end %>
```

pagination.js

```
$(function() {
  $(".pagination a").on('click', function(){
    $(".pagination").html("Page is loading...");
    $.getScript(this.href);
    return false;
  });
});
```

It somehow works for a index action, ajax method works for the links but when the I click on the last or the first page links generates like **localhost:3000/control?_=1463743428904&page=1** also, when ever I hit the search, the pagination links throws link like
**localhost:3000/control/search?from_date=2016-05-18&page=2&to_date=2016-05-20&utf8=%E2%9C%93** which should be like **localhost:3000/control?page=1**. Is there any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define this:

```
self.per_page = 10
```

In your model which you are trying to paginate

Also you could try your search method like this:

```
@transactions = Transaction.where(:created_at => params[:from_date].to_datetime..(params[:to_date].to_datetime + 1.day)).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not working since I tried this already. Defining self.per_page = 10 in model is just a identifier only, so that we don't need to set the per page value in our controller. But my problem is not this. I problem is with the url.